# digitally sign pdf using itext with pkcs 7 files

Tags: pdf, itext, pkcs#7

I was using pkcs 12 (.pfx)for signing pdf document but how to achieve using pkcs 7 in C#.is there any sample or documentation for signing pdf using pkcs 7? I have p7b and cer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sign the data using a file in PKCS#7 format. This is because PKCS#7 contains only certificates without private keys, and to sign something you need to have a private key.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. But my client has provided me only two files (.p7b and .cer) to sign their business documents programmatically. They used to sign pdf using USB Key like pendrive. I just want to know that for signing any doc, should we need pfx file? if I don't have pfx then how to convert pkcs#7 standard files to PKCS#2 format to sign doc using pfx.

Comment: @user2638841 The client provided the public part. The private key is contained in the USB token and can not be extracted from this token (even if the client wanted). The client needs to find the private key or request the certificate to be reissued (and the keys regenerated) so that he could then create a PFX and give it to you.